# How to sum quantity in sql

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

I have a simple table with these columns:

```
Id, quantity, deleted
```

`Deleted` is nullable.

I want to get sum of quantity of all rows,sum of quantity of rows that deleted is null, sum of quantity of rows that deleted is not null
in one query.

How can I do that?

Comment: _Columns_, not fields. Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Do sub queries count as 1 query?

Comment: hint: SUM()  WHERE deleted is null

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Postgres.in real scenario i have heavy joins and i dont want use a subquery for each of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sum over a couple of `case` expressions:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN deleted IS NULL THEN quantity END) AS sum_deleted_is_null,
       SUM(CASE WHEN deleted IS NOT NULL THEN quantity END) AS sum_deleted_is_not_null
FROM   mytable
```